# Operator '+' is not defined for std::string and std:string_view

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there any special reason that `operator+` isn't defined for `std::string` and `std::string_view`? I find it's weird.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std::literals;

int main()
{
    // That's OK
    std::cout << "Hello,"s + " World!" << std::endl;
    // Here at least GCC complains 
    std::cout << "Hello, "s + " World!"sv << std::endl;
}
```